# Batch file and path to .exe from a program

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to start a program with a batch file but I have some problems with the path!

This is what I have after trying some thing.
The program also have to start minimized...

```
 start /b/min "C:\Program Files (x86)\GoToTags\GoToTags Windows App\GoToTags.WindowsApp.exe"
```

Or what is the path to a desktop shortcut?

Comment: you are missing the closing quote from the executable name. The first quoted argument of a `start` command is used as the windows title. It's allowable to use an empty string as the windows title, hence `start ... "" "executablename" parameters` is allowable

Comment: @Magoo Indeed no it starts after 3 or more times, else I get this error "Can't start the program correct" (0xc0000142)

Comment: see `start /?`, read about `/b` to learn why not to use it here. What has "the path to a desktop shortcut"  to do do with your problem? (btw: it's `%homepath%\Desktop\`)

Comment: A general desktop path can be written as "%UserProfile%\Desktop" so something like this `"%UserProfile%\Desktop\GoToTags.lnk"` with your desktop shortcut already set to minimized would work. Even with the minimized option set in your shortcut, you would problably need to use `Start` with or without the `/B` option; `Start/B "" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\GoToTags.lnk"`.